# Naturalization interview - US Passport instead of Birth Certificate

Tags: citizenship, us-citizens

We are about to enter the interview process on our Application for Naturalization as part of the United State Citizenship and Immigration Service.

We received a letter with the following statement in order to prepare for the interview.

You MUST BRING the following with you to the interviewing
If applying for NATURALIZATION AS THE SPOUSE of a United State Citizen
* Your marriage certificate
* Proof of death or divorce for each prior marriage of yourself or spouse
* Your spouses's birth of naturalization certificate or certification of citizenship

Is a US Passport not a better proof of citizenship than a birth certificate, is there any reason they don't list this is as an option

Comment: Does your spouse's US passport show that he/she has been a US citizen for at least 3 years (e.g. the passport was issued at least 3 years ago)?

Comment: Yes in this case it would but I see why they don't mention it as an option! (The requirement being citizen for 3 years)

Comment: @user102008 wouldn't a passport showing a place of birth in the US suffice even if it were less than three years old?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion a US passport (or US passports) that shows that your spouse has been a US citizen for at least 3 years should be enough. The [document checklist for N-400](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/attachments.pdf) lists a US passport as one the forms of evidence that can be used to prove that the spouse has been a US citizen for at least 3 years. So they should accept the same evidence at the interview too.

Comment: I will gently observe that having been given clear instructions on what documents to produce, the OP risks a finding of non-compliance by taking another tack. The OP may be correct legally speaking, but as when arguing with authoritarian folks in uniforms (TSA comes to mind), the customer is either usually or always wrong.

Comment: @David I would agree.  Based on the requested documents, it seems they are interested in knowing WHEN and HOW the spouse became a citizen, which can impact their ability to pass on citizenship.

Comment: @Eric: When and how the spouse became a citizen are irrelevant here as long as the spouse has been a US citizen for at least 3 years.